# $u=f(v)$ for $f\in C^1(\Bbb R)$ implies Poisson bracket of $u$ and $v$ is zero. Is the converse also true?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Consider the Poisson bracket of two differentiable functions $u$ and $v$ given by
$$[u,v]=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}.$$
It is clear that if $u=f(v)$ for some $f\in C^1(\Bbb R)$ then by Chain rule
$$[u,v]=[f(v),v]=f'(v)\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\frac{\partial v}{\partial y} - f'(v)\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=0.$$
Now is the converse true? I.e if $[u,v]=0$ then there exists $f\in C^1(\mathbb{R})$ such that $u=f(v)$?

Some hints would be great!

Comment: $u$ arbitrary and $v = 0$ (or any constant) would be a simple counterexample.

Comment: This can't be true because the relation $[u,v]=0$ is symmetric, but $u=f(v)$ is not. For instance, $[x,x^2]=0$ but $x\ne f(x^2)$.

Comment: Thank you for the counter-examples. Suppose that $u,v\neq 0$. Is the converse at least 'locally' true in some way?

Comment: A more reasonable conclusion is that if $(u_x,u_y) \ne (0,0)$, then there exists a function $f$ such that $v = f(u)$. This can be proved using the implicit function theorem.